# PowerShell 5.1 v PWSH Out-File

Tags: powershell, text, formatting, powershell-core

More of a curiosity question. Has anyone noticed a difference between PS(5.1) vs pwsh(7.2.1) and using the `Out-File` cmdlet?

Im talking more along the lines of you run a script in PS and it outputs a file `test.log` in this instance using `out-file`. And then you run the same script in `pwsh` and outputing to the same file with `-Append` and the text just shows as japanese(?) characters.

```
PowerShell 5 Test Text
PowerShell 5 Test Text
潐敷卲敨汬㜠吠獥⁴敔瑸਍潐敷卲敨汬㜠吠獥⁴敔瑸਍
```

The last line is what appears when running `pwsh`:

```
"PowerShell 7 Test Text" | Out-File "C:\Source\Scripts\ScriptLog\test.log" -Append
```

When doing the reverse `pwsh` to `PowerShell` the text appears, but it is formatted with spaces:

```
PowerShell 7 Test Text
P o w e r S h e l l   5   T e s t   T e x t
```

Do the two programs just format text files differently? Or is there a way to have them format the same?

We are slowly working `pwsh` into being the norm but have to do quite a bit of regression testing to ensure things work properly and this is one thing I've been seeing that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Well in doing some of my own digging/testing in the meantime. I found that if I specify `-Encoding oem` that seems to allow the outputs to match and be in a normal text format no matter what terminal I run from

```
"PowerShell 7 Test Text" | Out-File "C:\Source\Scripts\ScriptLog\test.log" -Append -Encoding oem
```

Answer (score 0):

`Out-file -append` and `>>` do not check the current file encoding, so they can mix utf16 and utf8 in the same file.  I would recommend `add-content` instead.